# Find the value of $\log_{5}(0.0016)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Find the value of $\log_{5}(0.0016)$

$y=\log_{5}(0.0016)=\log_{5}(0.2)^4 \Rightarrow 5^y=(0.2)^4$

$\Rightarrow \log5^y=\log(0.2)^4$

$\Rightarrow y\log5=4\log(\dfrac{1}{5})$

$\Rightarrow y\log5=4(\log1-\log5)$

$\Rightarrow y\log5=-4\log5$

$\Rightarrow (y+4)\log5=0$

This is wrong, but I can't see where in my calculations I made a mistake. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This seems fine to me. What is the error that you think you have?

Comment: The last equation shows that $y=\log_{5}(0.0016)=-4$.

Comment: Easier is to find the logarithm, base $~10,~$ and then apply the scaling factor $~\log_5(10) = \dfrac{1}{\log_{10}(5)}.$

Comment: @CalvinLin Is $\log_5(0.2)^4$ the right notation? I would write it like $\log_5(0.2^4)=-4$.

Comment: @callculus42 It is fine to me, though I agree your version is much clearer. It is not like $f(x)$ where you need the entire input within the brackets. IE $f(x) ^4$ is interpreted as $[f(x)]^4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your working is fine and correct.

Here is a shorter working:

$$y=\log_5(0.2)^4=4\log_5(5^{-1})=-4$$